# Parsing an xml file and feed a list of objects with retrieved data

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

EDIT: Added a working solution for review at the bottom of the post.

So every-time I touch to xml I want to bang my head into a wall. Usually It's for writing a file and I finally manage to find a way around all the inconsistencies but this time I have to parse a document.

Here is the scene: I have an xml document listing games and each game as some attributes (or child nodes ? I am not sure actually). What I want is:

```
For each game:
 Gets it's path, name, and genre
 Build a Game object with this
 Store the object in an array list
```

I understand the "findall" command but I do not understand how to link the data between them. Since it is a tree, I suppose I should just be able to walk from game to game, get the data I need, and move on to the next game, but heck, I am stuck.

So here is an extract of the xml file I need to parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gameList>
    <provider>
        <System>Megadrive</System>
        <software>Skraper</software>
        <database>ScreenScraper.fr</database>
        <web>http://www.screenscraper.fr</web>
    </provider>
    <game id="574" source="ScreenScraper.fr">
        <path>./3 Ninjas Kick Back.zip</path>
        <name>3 Ninjas Kick Back</name>
        <genre>Platform-Action</genre>
    </game>
    <game id="394" source="ScreenScraper.fr">
        <path>./688 Attack Sub.zip</path>
        <name>688 Attack Sub</name>
        <genre>Simulation</genre>
    </game>
</gameList>
```

Here is my current code, in a sandbox, trying and experiencing state:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree


class GameListParser:
    GAMELIST_FILE = 'gamelist.xml'

    GAMELIST_KEY = "gameList"
    GAME_KEY = "game"
    GENRE_KEY = "genre"
    PATH_KEY = "path"
    NAME_KEY = "name"

    keys_map = {
        GAMELIST_KEY: {
            GAME_KEY: [NAME_KEY, GENRE_KEY, PATH_KEY]
        }
    }

    def __init__(self, gamelist_path):
        self.gamelist = os.path.join(gamelist_path, self.GAMELIST_FILE)
        self.parsed_gamelist = None
        self.__parse()

    def __parse(self):
        self.parsed_gamelist = ElementTree.parse(self.gamelist)

    def __get_root(self):
        return self.parsed_gamelist.getroot()

    def get_all_games(self):
        return self.parsed_gamelist.findall(self.GAME_KEY)

    def print_games_details(self):
        for node in self.get_all_games():
            for game in node.getiterator():
                name = game.attrib.get(self.NAME_KEY)
                genre = game.attrib.get(self.GENRE_KEY)
```

With the `print_games_details` method I simply hope to print the game data, but actually the node and game object are the same, so name and genre are None and I do not retrieve the data I need.

I am pretty sure it is simple, but I had to work with xml only 3 to 4 times in my life, the only time I had to parse into objects was with C++ and it was a system complete refactor. The two other times were in Matlab and Python in the direction objects to xml file. Each time I have trouble to grasp my head around the logic of the tree, how to parse/create it, and the online resources do not help me a lot.

EDIT: So I worked on a solution and while it gives me the result I expect I am not comfortable at all with it. 
My issue is that this solution implies that I know very well the structure of the xml file, when I would just walk it.

There's no way I can do something generic with it, and this is one of the main concern I have with my approach of xml.

If any of you could kindly review the following code and provide feedback and improvements I would greatly appreciate it:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree


class GameListParser:
    GAMELIST_FILE = 'gamelist.xml'

    GAME_ID = 'id'
    GAME_KEY = "game"
    GENRE_KEY = "genre"
    PATH_KEY = "path"
    NAME_KEY = "name"

    keys_map = [NAME_KEY, GENRE_KEY, PATH_KEY]
    game_map = {}

    def __init__(self, gamelist_path):
        self.gamelist = os.path.join(gamelist_path, self.GAMELIST_FILE)
        self.parsed_gamelist = None
        self.__parse()

    def __str__(self):
        text_output = []

        for game_id, game in self.game_map.items():
            text_output.append("Game " + game_id + " has properties:")
            for key, value in game.items():
                text_output.append(key + ": " + value)
            text_output.append("\n")

        return "\n".join(text_output)

    def __get_game_id(self, game):
        return game.get(self.GAME_ID)

    def __game_is_valid(self, game):
        return self.__get_game_id(game) is not None

    def __get_all_games(self):
        return self.parsed_gamelist.findall(self.GAME_KEY)

    def __process_all_games(self):
        for game in self.__get_all_games():
            self.__process_game_nodes(game)

    def __process_game_nodes(self, game):

        if self.__game_is_valid(game):

            details = {}
            self.game_map[self.__get_game_id(game)] = details

            for key in self.keys_map:
                game_child = game.find(key)
                if game_child is not None:
                    details[key] = game_child.text
                else:
                    details[key] = ""

    def __parse(self):
        self.parsed_gamelist = ElementTree.parse(self.gamelist)
        self.__process_all_games()
```

Comment: So, you are only concerned about the `print_games_details` method?

Comment: What exactly is thew question/problem? Looks like you made it complicated with your second attempt.

Comment: No, my problem was getting the datas, the print is just a step to make sure I process them correctly. They will be processed in a static List of Games and then some postreatment will be applied to the actual files. It seems complex because I decouple my code in favor of flexibility and further developments. I will however simplify it using SimplifiedDoc but the structure will stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommend a third-party library: SimplifiedDoc. pip install -U simplified_scrapy

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc
html = '''
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<gameList>
    <provider>
        <System>Megadrive</System>
        <software>Skraper</software>
        <database>ScreenScraper.fr</database>
        <web>http://www.screenscraper.fr</web>
    </provider>
    <game id="574" source="ScreenScraper.fr">
        <path>./3 Ninjas Kick Back.zip</path>
        <name>3 Ninjas Kick Back</name>
        <genre>Platform-Action</genre>
    </game>
    <game id="394" source="ScreenScraper.fr">
        <path>./688 Attack Sub.zip</path>
        <name>688 Attack Sub</name>
        <genre>Simulation</genre>
    </game>
</gameList>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
games = doc.gameList.games
datas = [[g.path.text,g.name.text,g.genre.text] for g in games]
print (datas)
```

Result:

```
[['./3 Ninjas Kick Back.zip', '3 Ninjas Kick Back', 'Platform-Action'], ['./688 Attack Sub.zip', '688 Attack Sub', 'Simulation']]
```

Here are more examples:https://github.com/yiyedata/simplified-scrapy-demo/tree/master/doc_examples

Comment: That seems great I will have a detailed look at it thanks !